# Set value to slice of a Pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I want to sort a subset of a dataframe (say, between indexes i and j) according to some value. I tried

```
df2=df.iloc[i:j].sort_values(by=...)
df.iloc[i:j]=df2
```

No problem with the first line but nothing happens when I run the second one (not even an error). How should I do ? (I tried also the update function but it didn't do either).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe need assign to filtered `DataFrame` with converting to numpy array by [`values`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.values.html) for avoid align indices:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': [1,2,3,4,3,2,1,4,1,2]})
print (df)
   A
0  1
1  2
2  3
3  4
4  3
5  2
6  1
7  4
8  1
9  2

i = 2
j = 7
df.iloc[i:j] = df.iloc[i:j].sort_values(by='A').values
print (df)
   A
0  1
1  2
2  1
3  2
4  3
5  3
6  4
7  4
8  1
9  2
```

Comment: Sorry, need `.values` for converting to `numpy array`